# Programmatically validate JAXB pojos

Tags: java, xml, validation, jaxb

We have a jaxws based webservice that uses JAXB pojos to define the model. The WSDL gets generated. Those pojos already contain validation information like `@XmlElement(nillable=false)` etc. Is there a way to validate such pojos programmatically, e.g. in unit tests?

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Person
    private String name;

    @XmlSchemaType(name="string")
    @XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

@Test
public void nameIsSet() {
    Person p = new Person();
    // Howto validate p so that it matches the constraints?
}
```

The idea is to reuse the pojos for programmatic creation and manipulation (not via XML) without having to add bean validation annotations as well:

```
    @XmlSchemaType(name="string")
    @XmlElement(required=true,nillable=false)
    @NotNull // I don't want to add this
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are after, but I guess you could try to marshall the POJO, which should fail if invalid.

Comment: See http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html

Comment: @artbristol: The blog post you mentioned uses a schema. In our case, the schema gets generated at runtime by jaxws - so there is no schema available during compile time. Any ideas?

Comment: @user2310289: Just tried to marshal an invalid pojo, but it does not raise any errors during marshalling.

Comment: @James You could generate the schema at compilation time using XJC, I suppose